# Get Public IP Address on current EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using Amazon CLI, is there a way to get the public ip address of the current EC2?  I'm just looking for the single string value, so not the json response describe-addresses returns.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can be used to return information on any/all Amazon EC2 instances, eg:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-0c9c9b44b --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress' --output text

54.232.200.77
```

If you are seeking information about the EC2 instance from which you are executing the command, then the current IP address can be obtained via the [instance metadata service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval):

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
iam/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
```

So, the **private IP address** is available via:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4

172.31.10.221
```

The **public IP address** is available via:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

54.232.200.77
```

Comment: I have added two public ip address and I have used curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 command but it showing the IP address that I have added recently. Is there a way to list all public ip address in an instance?

Comment: @Techiescorner you can run something like `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/09:34:54:0a:9b:4a/public-ipv4s` to get the public IP for each interface using their mac address (you can get that from `ifconfig-a` )

Comment: Duke's suggestion below to hit checkip.amazonaws.com is simpler and requires no access to instance profile or IAM credentials, which may be restrcted in some environments.(running on CI provider for instance)

Comment: On Windows I has to use double quotes for it to work on command prompt

Comment: This doesn't work, but `curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com` works.

Answer (score 128):

```sh
curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com
```

this returns the public ip address.

Comment: Was there an official documentation from AWS about this web service? Or is it some of those hacky ones? By the way **https** also works for that web service. Great answer there!

Comment: This is really interesting. Https is considerably slower than http, and, of course, both are much slower than curling http://169.254.169.254 (which does not allow for https).

Comment: They have documented it in a small note here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-sg.html#configuring-a-security-group

Comment: For me, today, on a generally restricted AWS server, only [https://checkip.amazonaws.com](https://checkip.amazonaws.com) (with https, not http) worked, and not the http version.

Answer (score 15):

If you are inside the instance -

```
$ curl icanhazip.com
162.202.17.123
```

here is one more way

```
$ curl -s ifconfig.me
162.202.17.123
```

these methods are not limited to just AWS.

Comment: Personally, I try and avoid these websites as I don't have control over what they capture and log around a public address.

Better to use a controlled endpoint under your own infrastructure, aws cli, or curl on 169.254.169.254 as per the other answers.

Comment: They'll also get sick of paying for the domain name and hosting one day, and your service will suddenly stop working because it can't resolve the random stranger's domain name and free service that you built a dependency on.

Comment: indeed they started blocking calls from AWS.

Comment: I have added one more way of getting ip.

Answer (score 2):

From  inside instnace type following command :

```
curl -s v4.ident.me
```

Answer (score 1):

Get attached InstanceID with PublicIP.

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query NetworkInterfaces[*].[Attachment.[InstanceId],Association.[PublicIp]] --output=json
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the ec2 linux images (e.g. debian 10) include a pre-installed [ec2metadata](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-utils/blob/main/bin/ec2metadata) cli tool which can retrieve the current vm's public ip among other metadata.

```
ec2metadata --public-ipv4
```

Answer (score 0):

For the New Users who are confused why the AWS ec2 Metadata API call giving a 401 answer please refer this:

The Metadata Service **Version 2** is session based and it expects a session token to create access to the Meta Data API.

A token can be created using the below command:

```
TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"
```

and once the token is generated, use it to call the top-level items from Metadata API service as below:

```
curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

For more details please refer the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-metadata-v2-how-it-works.html)