# migration of EC2 instance to a different subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I migrate an EC2 instance to a different subnet with the same static IP Address (NOT ELASTIC ADDRESS)?

Comment: You can't. If it is important that the public IP address doesn't change, you should be using an Elastic IP instead of letting Amazon auto-assign the public IP.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228441/keep-same-ip-address-for-ec2-instance

Answer (score 2):

To "migrate" an Amazon EC2 instance, you actually need to **create a new Amazon EC2 instance**. However, you can copy across the disk contents, so it appears to be the same instance.

To retain a public IP address, you should be using an **Elastic IP address**. This is a *static IP address* that is allocated to your AWS Account. You can then assign the IP address to any instance in the same region.

If you are *not* using an Elastic IP address, then **it is not possible to keep the IP address**. (It is not *static*.)

Steps:

- Use **Create image** to create an AMI of the existing instance. This takes a copy of the disks attached to the instance.
- **Launch a new EC2 instance**, specifying this new AMI and changing whatever settings you wish (eg subnet)
- **Reassociate the Elastic IP address** to the new instance
- **Delete the old instance** once you are happy that everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

-> Elastic IP address means Static or fixed IP address, other than that what ever public IP you receive during a session is temporary.

-> AWS will reassign you new public IP address when you start or stop your instance in a span of 5 to 10 minutes. ( irrespective of which subnet you are).

->**Hence if you want to migrate EC2 instance with the same IP address, you need to assign an ELastic IP address**.You can refer to this [moving ec2 instances to another subnet](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/)

Comment: I don't think the public IP address changes for a "Reboot" (since this is done in the OS only), but it will typically change when there is a Stop and Start.

Comment: That's absolutely correct @john, thank you for the input, I will update the answer.